# Use python to iterate over cells in excel range and copy values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I have 3 tables like below in excel. This is more a python for loop question and less a excel question (but it still involves excel)

```
ID,Name,Age,Subject
1,abc,21,maths
2,def,28,science
3,rew,38,social

ID,Name,Age,Subject
11,adbc,21,maths
23,dedf,28,science
39,rewd,38,social

ID,Name,Age,Subject
111,ancbc,21,maths
232,dedsf,28,science
391,rewsdd,38,social
```

So, my table range for values is given below

```
Table1 = D18:G20  (1st row,1st column is D18 (value is 1) and last row, last column is G20 (value is social)
Table2 = Q18:T20
Table3 = AB18:AE20
```

I would like to do the below

a) Copy `D18th` value to `Q18` and `AB18th`.

b) Similarly copy `D19th` value to `Q19th` and `AB19th`

c) Repeat this to copy each cell value from Table1 to Table2 and Table3

So, I was trying like below (using Xlwings which allows us to copy range)

```
sheet1.range("D18:G18").copy()
sheet1.range("Q18:T18").paste()
sheet1.range("AB18:AE18").paste()
sheet1.range("D19:G19").copy()
sheet1.range("Q19:T19").paste()
sheet1.range("AB19:AE19").paste()
sheet1.range("D20:G20").copy()
sheet1.range("Q20:S20").paste()
sheet1.range("AB20:AE20").paste()
```

But the above is not elegant/efficient. You can see am writing individual line for each range.

Is there any python way to do this over loop where at every iteration
a specified range is copied and pasted to the provided multiple destination area

**update - input excel screenshot with 2 tables**

[image]

Comment: If you can, share the excel file

Comment: Easier to script a solution with the excel file than a screenshot

Comment: Upload it somewhere ... Maybe google drive and then share the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly suggested, a for loop should suffice, a double for loop (using openpyxl) :

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
source = ws['D18':'G20']
table2 = ws['Q18':'T20']
table3 = ws['AB18':'AE20']

for row1, row2, row3 in zip(source, table2, table3):
    for cell1, cell2, cell3 in zip(row1, row2, row3):
        cell2.value = cell1.value
        cell3.value = cell1.value

wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: One quick question. we can't copy ranges and assign values based on ranges? In that way we can reduce the number of iteration. Currently, we do cell by cell. Is it possible to range by range? Meaning, for example, copy all values from `D18:G23` and paste it to `Q18:S23`?

Comment: I don't think openpyxl offers that option of a range(essentially you are referring to row assignment). there might be other libraries though that offer this abstraction